# PHP values to js file via json

Tags: javascript, php, json

I have some php variables and i want to send the values to a js file via json. What i have so far:

```
<?php
$data = array('artist' =>  $artistname, 'title' => $songname);

echo json_encode($data); // display encoded data.
?>
```

Output example :

```
{"artist":"Nirvana","title":"Breed (Rough Mix)"}
```

and the JS Function:

```
function radioInfo() {
    $.ajax({
        url: 'content.php?q=info',
        cache: false,
        dataType: 'json',
        timeout: phpvars.ajaxtimeout,
        success: function(data) {
            if (data == null) { return false; }

            $('.stream-info .artist').html('<a data-title="' + data.artist + '" href="#">' + shorten(data.artist, phpvars.artist_maxlen) + '</a>');
            $('.stream-info .title').html('<a data-title="' + data.title + '" href="#">' + shorten(cleartrack(data.title), phpvars.title_maxlen) + '</a>');
        }
    }});
}
```

Comment: And your problem is... ?

Comment: values aren't parsed in the js function.

Comment: But this can happens by so many reasons. Did you checked the request status in the dev tools(f12 -> network) ?

Comment: The request is fine. I was wondering  if the json output is valid. or if there is something wrong with the function

Comment: I don't see a problem, what the `console.log(data);` says? Is the one you expect? What do you mean `values aren't parsed?`, what `specific` values?

Comment: There are no errors in the console log. the js file should send some data to the rendered html file: <div class="artist">value should appear here</div>.. but i see this <div class="artist"></div>

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to send the header in your php file before you send the json:

If the content-type is set correctly, jquery and every other framework will parse your json.

```
<?php
header('Cache-Control: no-cache, must-revalidate');
header('Expires: Mon, 26 Jul 1997 05:00:00 GMT');
header('Content-Type: application/json');
flush();

$data = array('artist' =>  $artistname, 'title' => $songname);

echo json_encode($data); // display encoded data.
exit;
?>
```

Comment: Thanks, the json looks valid now, but still the problem is not solved.

Comment: Well, This solved the problem after all. Thank you so much Raphael.

Comment: This happens, I think, because of the `dataType: "json"`. If you remove it, it will probably work without those header. @PaulV if you don't want to set header on every ajax requests, try removing that `dataType`. Anyway, +1 for the answer.